# Jstree lazyloading and expand all issue

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, jstree

We are experiencing an issue when using the lazyloading feature and open_all feature together.

The contents of the tree are loaded using lazy loading feature.

When we select a node and click on expand all button, all the child nodes of that node will be fetched using jstree ajax call and opened using the open_all function, when clicking collapse all button, we are using close_all function. This works perfectly for the first time.

But on second time, when we click on expand all on the same node, same ajax url is hit on recursively. ( We think, the url is hit on every time on opening a node using open_all). The intended behaviour is not to call the url(as data is already loaded), only the open_all function should be executed.

Could you please clarify how to fix the issue

//code to load the tree

```
 $("#TreePanel").jstree({
    "xml_data" : {
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "/ajax/loadTree",
            "type" : "post",
            "data" : function(node) {
                var data = {};              
                data.dunsNumber = ${dunsNumber};
                if (node == -1) {
                    //set duns number to data
                } else {
                    data.selectedNodeId = node.attr("id");
                    data.expandAll = isExpandAll;
                }
                return data;
            },
            "success" : function(data) {
                if ($(data).attr('id') == 'error') {
                    $("#overlayContent").empty();                       
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }
         },
         "xsl" : "nest"
    },  
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]  
});


        //code to expand all nodes


       $("#ufvExpandAll").bind("click", function() {
    isExpandAll= true;
    $("#TreePanel").jstree("open_all", selectedNode);
    isExpandAll= false;
  });

      //code to collapse all nodes

$("#ufvCollapseAll").bind("click", function() {
    $("#TreePanel").jstree("close_all", selectedNode);
});

    //code to get the node and set on a variable on clicking a node

      var selectedNode;
$("#TreePanel").delegate("a", "click", function(e, data) {
    var node = $(e.target).closest("li");
    if (selectedNode != undefined && selectedNode != null) {
        $("#" + selectedNode.id + " > a").removeClass("jstree-default-             selected-node");
    }
    selectedNode = node[0];
    $("#" + selectedNode.id + " > a").addClass("jstree-default-selected-                 node");
        $("#ufvExpandAll").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#ufvCollapseAll").attr("disabled", false);
    return false;
});
```

Thanks In Advance

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 1):

Try to inspect the node to see if it has any pre-existing children before executing logic to load it with children.

```
.bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
  var node = $(data.rslt.obj);
  var children = $.jstree._reference(node)._get_children(node);
  if (children.length==0){
    //node is empty, so do node open logic here
  }
})
```